# White screen WebView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using Xamarin for my application
After I start the application I get a white screen, how can I solve the problem

```
        <StackLayout>
             <WebView Source="https://www.radio.md/" x:Name="Browser" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="600"></WebView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't included any relevant code so it's impossible to comment on what you may be doing wrong

Comment: How can I solve the problem?

Comment: is your page loading?  if you add a label or something above the webview can you see it?  Does your app have connectivity?

Comment: It is a site with radio channels,I just wrote these lines of code.You can open the site to see what it's all about.Thank you very much!

Comment: You aren't actually answering my questions.  If you want people to help you, you need to actually answer our questions.

Comment: Soory. The web page loads in the browser,I am connected to the internet, if I change the URL from another website it works but this http and wants to start, when the application starts only the white screen appears something nothing

Comment: there are issues with your SSL certificate that might cause the page to not load.  Have you checked the console for any error messages? See http://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker?su=a3b4d5c1e9e30b377f7bfbd97471778f

Comment: Could it be the problem in the ssl certificate?

Comment: that is exactly what I just told you.  "there are issues with your SSL certificate that might cause the page to not load"

Comment: Thank you very much, I solve the question and I will come back with an answer. Have a good day!!!!!!!!!!!